# Export data from php to html webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, web-services

Still new to this topic, I was wondering if there was a way for me to export data from php into a html webpage. In this particular case I'm trying to make it so that the system can check the data when an already registered user logs in and compares them with the user's input. The problem is I don't know how to take the user's data saved in the database (In this case $row) when the header switches into the next html webpage to be used.

```
<?php

$Email = $_POST['Ema'];
$Contraseña = $_POST['Cont'];

if(empty($Email) || empty($Contraseña)){
     echo ("Hablamos1");
     exit();
}
mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die("Error al conectar " . 
mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('isoft') or die ("Error al seleccionar la Base de datos: " . 
mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from usuarios where Email='" . $Email . "'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['Contraseña'] == $Contraseña) {
        session_start();
        header("Location: prueba.php");
    }else{
        echo("Hablamos");
        exit();
    }
}else{
     echo("hablamos")
     exit();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run the SQL on the new page (ex. prueba.php), or pass them as parameters to the URL you are redirecting to:

```
header("Location: prueba.php?record_id=" . urlencode($row['id']));
```